# mysql nested select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am newbie for relational tables. As i learn more, i see many advantages of sql statement. However i stuck on some point.

i look for if can get a single table for desired data-set from 5 tables. One of the table named 'eta' is used to connect other 4 tables.

Aim:
A phone number or email can be used by many users, and users may also have multiple phone number or email address. I want to list the phone numbers or email addresses with the user name that uses them.

Sample Data:
Please  check http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60acce  for the table structure and sample data-set

The final expected final result for the phone case as follow:

```
  phone            name    extra
  45336467      ABC Co.   
  45336467      Gery      114
  45336467      Todd      117
  45336467      Adam      119
```

Thanks

Edit: Explanation for the table relation.

table 'eta' has 4 fields which have table relations. column 'own' shows the company, person etc  value 'f' for company and 'k' for person others will used for different tables

v1_id for id of own field's referred table..

column 'res' refers to email and phone tables. value 't' for phone and 'e' for email.
v2_id for id of res field's referred table

Comment: Can you please explain the relations between the tables?

Comment: How does `eta` relate to any of the other tables?  What is the criteria to return the above?  If a person can have multiple phone numbers, which one do you want returned?

Comment: Specifically, how the fields on the `eta` table relates with the other tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After filing through your schema, I believe the following query should work for you:

```
SELECT
    phone.tel AS phone,
    CASE WHEN person.name IS NULL THEN company.titles ELSE person.name END AS name,
    eta.extra AS extra
FROM
    eta
    LEFT JOIN person
        ON eta.v1_id = person.id
        AND eta.own = 'k'
    LEFT JOIN company
        ON eta.v1_id = company.id
        AND eta.own = 'f'
    JOIN phone
        ON phone.id = eta.v2_id
WHERE
    eta.res = 't'
```

This assumes that `eta.res = 't'` if the relationship is to the "phone" table. Also, `eta.own = 'k'` for people, `eta.own = 'f'` for companies.

It uses two left joins to pull from the `person`/`company` tables so that it can accomplish the pulls in a single query. If the `person.name` column is null, that means the current record is from the `company` table and will select that value instead (for the name column).

The same can be done to select the email addresses (assuming `eta.res = 'e'` to relate to the email table):

```
SELECT
    email.email AS email,
    CASE WHEN person.name IS NULL THEN company.titles ELSE person.name END AS name
FROM
    eta
    LEFT JOIN person
        ON eta.v1_id = person.id
        AND eta.own = 'k'
    LEFT JOIN company
        ON eta.v1_id = company.id
        AND eta.own = 'f'
    JOIN email
        ON email.id = eta.v2_id
WHERE
    eta.res = 'e'
```

Comment: And it works flawlessly, check [SQL Fiddle code.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/60acce/21) +1 for "guessing" relationships, I was still guessing when you posted the answer

Comment: Great!!  it works perfect.  Can we use it by adding one more table for such as 'department'. it checks null state, what if there is three tables ?

Comment: @aliaktas Yeah, you should be able to add as many more tables as you'd want. For each table, you'll just need to add `LEFT JOIN new_table ON eta.v1_id = new_table.id AND eta.own = '?'`. Also, you'll need to change the `CASE` statement to support it to `CASE WHEN person.name IS NOT NULL THEN person.name WHEN company.titles IS NOT NULL THEN company.titles ELSE new_table.name_field END AS name` (note, I changed it to `IS NOT NULL` here)